# jquery strange button behavior

Tags: jquery, button, if-statement

I am in mobile app. I use a button that on click checks if gtotal is greater than total and alerts a message. Here is my code

```
        $("#pay").unbind('click').click(function(e) {
            barcodeTotal();
            if (gtotal > total){
                alert("Too much money");
                $('#shares').val('');
                payment = 0;
                gtotal = 0; 
                $("#Payment").html('<p class="total">Total Payment: <strong>' + payment.toFixed(2) + '</strong></p>');
                return false;
            }
            updateItem(payment.toFixed(2), gtotal, barcode, barcodeamount, barcodeprevious, allbarcode);
        });
```

I have the following problem. The alert pops up on every click without if statement check...

Where am i wrong?

please advice

this is total calculation

```
        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
            row = resultflatname.rows.item(i);
            if (row.receiptno == 0){
                items.push('<input type="checkbox" name="code_'+ i +'" id="code_'+ i +'" value="' + row.amount + '" previous="' + row.pastpayments + '" barcode="' + row.barcode + '" todayp="' + row.todaypayments + '"/><label for="code_'+ i +'">' + row.period +'..........'+ row.amount+'</label>');
            } else {
            if ((row.receiptno > 0) && (row.amount > row.todaypayments + row.pastpayments)){
                items.push('<input type="checkbox" name="code_'+ i +'" id="code_'+ i +'" value="' + row.amount + '" previous="' + row.pastpayments + '" barcode="' + row.barcode + '" todayp="' + row.todaypayments + '"/><label for="code_'+ i +'">' + row.period +'..........'+ row.amount+'</label>');
            }
        }
                allbarcode[i] = row.barcode;
                previouspayments1 = previouspayments1 + row.pastpayments;
                previouspayments = previouspayments1.toFixed(2);
                sofeilon1 = sofeilon1 + row.amount;
                sofeilon = sofeilon1.toFixed(2);
                total1 = sofeilon - previouspayments;
                total = total1.toFixed(2);
```

and this is gtotal calculation

```
        $('#shares').keyup(function(){
            payment = 0;
            calcTotal();
            gtotal = ($('#shares').val() * 1) + payment;
            gtotal = gtotal.toFixed(2);
            $("p.total").html("Total Payment: <strong>" + gtotal + "</strong>");
        });


        $('#shares').keyup(function(){
            $("input:checkbox, input:radio").click(function() {
                payment = 0;
                calcTotal();
                gtotal = ($('#shares').val() * 1) + payment;
                gtotal = gtotal.toFixed(2);
                $("p.total").html("Total Payment: <strong>" + gtotal + "</strong>");
            });
        });
```

and calctotal function

```
        function calcTotal() {
            $("input:checked").each(function() {
                var value = [$(this).attr("value")]-[$(this).attr("previous")];
                payment = payment + parseFloat(value); //total = total + value          
            });
        }
```

Comment: Show us where you define gtotal and total as it seems that gtotal is always > than total

Comment: Where are gtotal and total being calculated? Please show the code where they are being calculated.

Comment: We'll need more info to help you out. Where are gtotal and total set?

Comment: no i check it the alert pops up even if gtotal < total

Comment: You're using global variables, aren't you? Could be part of the problem. (Modern thinking is to avoid those whenever possible.) Try rewriting `barcodeTotal()` to return a value that you can use in your function.

Comment: Change `alert("Too much money");` to a debugging line: `alert("gtotal="+gtotal+" total="+total);` and see what you get.

Comment: gtotal=76.40total=107.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should debug the variables `gtotal` and `total` to view their data types.

```
console.log(gtotal, typeof(gtotal));
console.log(total, typeof(total));
```

If the values are strings the if-statement will return `true` as "76.40" is considered greater than "107.10".

Use [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to convert the strings to numbers.